# Mixed Array of String and Number

Tags: typescript

I have an array that consists of a string and number ("2",3,4). I want to multiply the same and get an output of 24.

I tried this method but getting an error of "Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."

```
var stringArray = ["2",3,4];
var numberArray = [];

length = stringArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  numberArray.push(parseInt(stringArray[i]));
console.log(numberArray);
```

Comment: I don't get this error and your code worked

Comment: In what context is this javascript being run? It works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to multiply.
`var stringArray = ["2",3,4]; let res = stringArray.reduce((a,b) => a*b);`
the Reduce method will do conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will check this out don't have much idea about Reduce method.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` expects and argument of type `string`. However, since your array also contains numbers, you are calling it with a `number`, eg. `parseInt(3)`, which is why you are getting the error.

A possible solution is to check manually and give a hint

```
var stringArray = ["2",3,4];
var numberArray = [];

length = stringArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  let value;
  if (typeof stringArray[i] === 'string') {
     value = parseInt(stringArray[i] as string)
  } else {
     value = stringArray[i]
  }
  numberArray.push(value);
}
console.log(numberArray);
```

Comment: A little variation using a `for...of` loop you can save a couple of lines and avoid using `as` thanks to type inference: https://tsplay.dev/WJq0Zm

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the + operator like this:

```js
var stringArray = ["2", 3, 4];

let res = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
  res *= +stringArray[i];
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution this seems the simplest way to do it as well I can update the content dynamically as well if needed by this.